# pynfs: error: gssapi/gssapi.h: No such file or directory

Tags: python, linux, nfs

I am trying to install pynfs on RHEL 6.4 based VM

command executed is python setup.py build, but I am getting this issue,
`error: gssapi/gssapi.h: No such file or directory`,

this issue is seen when setup.py build is executed for nfs4.0 directory,
Moving to nfs4.0
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'rpc.rpcsec._gssapi' extension
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -I/usr/kerberos/include -I/usr/include/python2.6 -c lib/rpc/rpcsec/gssapi_wrap.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/lib/rpc/rpcsec/gssapi_wrap.o -Wall
lib/rpc/rpcsec/gssapi_wrap.c:2521:27: error: gssapi/gssapi.h: No such file or directory
lib/rpc/rpcsec/gssapi_wrap.c:2528: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘krb5oid’
lib/rpc/rpcsec/gssapi_wrap.c:2575: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘krb5oid_ptr’
lib/rpc/rpcsec/gssapi_wrap.c:2588: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘reordered_init_sec_context’
lib/rpc/rpcsec/gssapi_wrap.c:2759: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘reordered_gss_accept_sec_context’
lib/rpc/rpcsec/gssapi_wrap.c:2777: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘reordered_gss_get_mic’
lib/rpc/rpcsec/gssapi_wrap.c:2788: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘reordered_gss_wrap’

Can somebody help me resolve this issue? Also, for fedora the similar way of installation works.

Answer (score 31):

For those on Ubuntu the package you need to install is libkrb5-dev

Answer (score 29):

```
sudo apt-get install -y libkrb5-dev
```

Comment: This is for Ubuntu/Debian. Thread is asking for RHEL.

Comment: I got this problem in a Debian like environment. Google sends me here, and @gebredingle answer helped me. Thumbs up to answer!

Answer (score 22):

You might need to install following package to resolve your issue.

```
yum install -y krb5-devel.
```

It worked for me in RHEL7 and centos7

Comment: Thanks, this helped me.

Comment: libkrb5-dev doesn't have a provider on Tumbleweed